# PEX Errors - VS2012 .NET 3.5

Tags: pex

I get the following error when I'm trying to run PEX in VS2010.

Microsoft.Pex.Engine.Libraries.MicrosoftVisualBasicLibrary+ProjectErrorRuntimeContextAttribute+Context failed to open.

Can someone please explain what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Look into the output window to see the error message.

Comment: Dude if you don't know - rather don't answer.

Comment: Trying to get more information here as the information you provided is probably not enough to get an answer. "Failed to open" reasons are often written to the output window.